# Renderbuffer needs to be bound before glFramebufferRenderbuffer?

Tags: opengl

The documentation of `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` only says that `renderbuffertarget` needs to be `GL_RENDERBUFFER`, though it does not specify that the attached renderbuffer, that is also given to the function, needs to be bound to `GL_RENDERBUFFER` beforehand.

I deem it not having to be so, because why would I have to specify the renderbuffer again if it should be bound beforehand?

Especially since the glNamedFramebufferRenderbuffer was introduced, it should not be nesseccary to bind anything.

Answer (score 3):

You must fully create a renderbuffer *before* you can attach it to an FBO.

The [pre-DSA OpenGL Object creation functions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Creation_and_Destruction) do not create objects; they create object *names*. It's like creating an uninitialized pointer variable; it doesn't point to anything yet.

The actual creation of the object happens the first time the name is bound to the context. At that moment, the name is given a real object.

Under normal circumstances, it was pretty much impossible to use an object *without* binding it to the context, so this distinction couldn't be noticed. However, once the ability to attach objects to one another came to be, this distinction became noticeable.

Pre-DSA, the only way to fully create a renderbuffer object was to bind it to the context.

However, with [ARB_DSA/GL 4.5](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Direct_State_Access), the `glCreate*` functions actually *create objects* (imagine that!). So if you use `glCreateRenderbuffers`, you can attach the renderbuffer to an FBO without binding it first.